# Offset do bootstrap não esta funcionando

Tags: html, bootstrap, offset

Estou fazendo o começo de um trabalho para o curso e no código o `<h1>`, `<hr>`, e o `<marquee>` não querem pular colunas com o `.offset`
Segue código:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1>Acróstico de Lucas</h1>
        </div>
    </div>              
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
            <hr color="black"></hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
            <marquee behavior="slide" direction="down" loop="1" scrolldelay="60">
                <ul>
                    <li><p><font color="red">L</font>eis, tais como casas, eles apoiam-se mutuamente,</p></li>  
                    <li><p><font color="red">U</font>m céu inexistente,<p></li>
                    <li><p><font color="red">C</font>ada nova idéia passa inevitavelmente,<p></li>
                    <li><p><font color="red">A</font> amadurecer, a ser criado se indefinidamente.<p></li>
                    <li><p><font color="red">S</font>angue e crescendo diariamente.<p></li>
                </ul>
            </marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quis dizer não querem pular *colunas*? Ou seja, não está ficando um *espaço em branco* à esquerda? Poderia postar uma imagem ou um fiddle?

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem de como roda

Comment: Você adicionou o arquivo **.css** do bootstrap no `<head></head>` do HTML?

Comment: Sim, tanto local quanto por CDN.

Comment: Ueh, peguei seu código e teste, está funcionando sim. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/6qjvjaq2/. Mude o tamanho da tela para verificar o funcionamento. Um detalhe, o offset respeita media query, então, se desejar ter offset em resoluções menores, defina as configurações de acordo com o tamanho da tela. Exemplo, col-sm-offset... col-xs-offset...

Comment: Com certeza falta vincular o Bootstrap no `<head>` da página. A prova disto é que as fontes estão em Times New Roman (default do navegador), enquanto o default do Bootstrap é uma fonte sans serif.